# How to disable submit button until all text fields are full and file is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, filechooser, disabled-input

I'm new to javascript / jquery so I may be missing something obvious, but I've found solutions that disable the submit button until all text fields are filled, and I've found solutions that disable it until a file is chosen. However, my form consists of a file input and 3 text fields and I cannot find a way of it being disabled until all text fields AND a file is chosen.

The distilled version of the code I'm working with is here:

HTML

```
    <div>
    <input type="file" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
    </div>
```

JS

```
    $('.submit').click(function() {
var empty = $(this).parent().find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length) {

        $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    });
})()
```

Thanks for your help

https://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/482/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try capture the event on those field and checking the empty values by using another function, see below code :

```
$(':input').on('change keyup', function () {
  // call the function after
  // both change and keyup event trigger
  var k = checking();
  // if value inc not 0
  if (k) $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
  // if value inc is 0
  else $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
});

// this function check for empty values
function checking() {
  var inc = 0;
  // capture all input except submit button
  $(':input:not(:submit)').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") inc++;
  });
  return inc;
}
```

This is just an example, but the logic somehow like that.

**Update :
Event Delegation.** You might need read **[this](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)**

```
 // document -> can be replaced with nearest parent/container
 // which is already exist on the page,
 // something that hold dynamic data(in your case form input)
 $(document).on('change keyup',':input', function (){..});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/kLrvac28/)

Comment: Thanks that fixes the jsfiddle, but for some reason it doesn't work with my actual code... Are there any possible reasons for this? It's in a form, uses placeholder text that is deleted on focus, uses a custom button and on click inserts the values into a database. Would any of those cause it not to work?

Comment: does the input fields on form was created dynamically? if yes, try delegating those by doing like this : `$(document).on('change keyup',':input', function (){..});`

Comment: That was it! Works perfectly now, thanks so much. I'd been stuck on that for ages!

Answer (score 1):

Please see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/482/

```
$('input').on('change',function(){
    var empty = $('div').find("input").filter(function() {
            return this.value === "";
        });

        if(empty.length>0) {

            $('.submit').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    else{
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

[1]:

Answer (score 1):

The trick is

- don’t disable the submit button; otherwise the user can’t click on it and testing won’t work
- only when processing, only return true if all tests are satisfied

Here is a modified version of the HTML:

```
<form id="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

and some pure JavaScript:

```
window.onload=init;
function init() {
    var form=document.getElementById('test');
    form.onsubmit=testSubmit;

    function testSubmit() {
        if(!form['file'].value) return false;
        if(!form['name'].value) return false;
        if(!form['email'].value) return false;
    }
}
```

Note that I have removed all traces of XHTML in the HTML. That’s not necessary, of course, but HTML5 does allow a simpler version of the above, without JavaScript. Simply use the `required` attribute:

```
<form id="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="file" name="file" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" required><br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

This prevents form submission if a required field is empty and works for all modern (not IE8) browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the `input` event on `file` and `text` input elements, count number of unfilled inputs and, set the submit button's `disabled` property based on that number. Check out the demo below.

```js
$(':text,:file').on('input', function() {
    //find number of unfilled inputs
    var n = $(':text,:file').filter(function() {
        return this.value.trim().length == 0;
    }).length;
    
    //set disabled property of submit based on number
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', n != 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="file" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" id="submit" disabled="disabled" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For my approach, I'd rather use `array` to store if all the conditions are `true`. Then use `every` to make sure that all is `true`

```
$(function(){
    function validateSubmit()
    {
       var result = [];
       $('input[type=file], input[type=text]').each(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == "")
            result.push(false);
          else
            result.push(true);
       });
       return result;
    }

    $('input[type=file], input[type=text]').bind('change keyup', function(){
       var res = validateSubmit().every(function(elem){
          return elem == true;
       });

       if (res)
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
       else
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xG2KS/485/)